# Signing only part of XML

Tags: java, xml, apache, signature

I want to sign only specific part of XML using XMLSignature only? (without using XMLSignatureFactory). The part of the XML we want to sign has a special ID associated with it, so it is enveloping signature.

I have the following code, and why is it failing on sig.addDocument(.....). **The error says Cannot resolve element with ID id-83**? We can see that the ID is there but XMLSignature could not find it. Any clue?

```
XMLSignature sig = new XMLSignature(doc,"",XMLSignature.ALGO_ID_SIGNATURE_RSA_SHA1);
Transforms transforms = new Transforms(doc);
transforms.addTransform(Transform.TRANSFORM_C14N11_OMIT_COMMENTS);
sig.addDocument("#id-83", transforms, org.apache.xml.security.utils.Constants.ALGO_ID_DIGEST_SHA1);
......
```

Before Signing

```
<soap:Envelope>
    <soap:Header>

    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body id="id-83">
        <createFruit>
             <Name>Apple</Name>
        </createFruit>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

After Signing

```
<soap:Envelope>
    <soap:Header>
         <ds:Signature>
              <ds:SignedInfo>
                    <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                    </ds:CanonicalizationMethod>
                    <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
                         <ds:Reference URI="#id-83">
                             <ds:Transforms>
                                  <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                             </ds:Transforms>
                             <ds:DigestValue>48743sgsdhd434</ds:DigestValue>
                         </ds:Reference>
              </ds:SignedInfo>
              ....SignatureValue, KeyInfo...
         </ds:Signature>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body id="id-83">
        <createFruit>
             <Name>Apple</Name>
        </createFruit>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```